# Linq join between two Lists

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to Linq. I have a requirement , There is 2 list, one is student list and another is mark list. In student we have id, name and in mark list id(sid), marks, subjects. Need to get out put as , student id, name, and total marks for each student. I have approached code as below,

```
 class Student
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
 }

 class Marks
 {
     public int Sid {get;set;}
     public int mark {get;set;}
     public string subjects {get;set;}
 }

 class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         //student
        List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>()
        {
             new Student() { Id = 1, name = "A" },
             new Student() { Id = 2, name = "B" }
        };

        //marks
        List<Marks> markList = new List<Marks>()
        {
            new Marks() { Sid = 1, mark = 30, subjects = "A1" },
            new Marks() { Sid = 1, mark = 40, subjects = "A2" },
            new Marks() { Sid = 2, mark = 40, subjects = "B1" },
            new Marks() { Sid = 1, mark = 50, subjects = "B2" }
        };

         var result=(from stu in studentList
                     join mar in markList 
                         on stu.Id equals mar.Sid                            
                     select new
                         {
                            stu.Id,
                            stu.name,
                            mar.mark,
                            mar.subjects
                         })
                     .GroupBy(x => x.subjects).ToList();
```

The above Linq query didn't meet my requirement. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question to indent the code more readably - and note that if you add a constructor to each of Student and Marks, and use collection initializers, you could write the same code *much* more readably and compactly. Now, what was the actual output, and what was your desired output? Please give more information than just "didn't meet my requirement". Don't forget that the purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers...

Comment: Use a join.  See webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = studentList
            .Join(markList, m => m.Id, s => s.Sid, (s, m) => new { s, m })
            .GroupBy(t => t.s)
            .Select(g => new 
            { 
                Student = g.Key, 
                MarksCount = g.Count(), 
                Marks = g.Select(x => x.m).ToList() 
            })
            .ToList();
```

MarksCount - total marks for this student
Marks - List of marks for this student